# Find the distribution of nlcd categories within polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, rasterstats, nlcd

I am new to QGIS.  I am trying to find out the distribution of NLCD bins within the buffered areas.  The buffered areas is a vector layer, while the other is the NLCD raster (downloaded from MLRC).  In summary I am trying to get for each circle how many points are in class 21, 22, 23, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact number of unique buffer polygons you have, my first recommendation is to use each buffer polygon (which should have a unique name & ID) to clip the NLCD raster to a new layer via **Raster > Extraction > Clip Raster By Mask Layer**.

From there, enter the **Properties** window of this new raster and navigate to the **Histogram** section. You will be able to compute the raster's histogram of values by clicking **Compute Histogram**, which should be fairly quick given the raster resolution based on image you've provided.

Should you have a lot of these buffers, you likely will want to merge all buffers into a single shapefile layer (multipolygon), then leverage the **Iterate over Each Feature** option in the Clip Raster By Mask Layer. This will loop through each of the buffer features and produce individual rasters for each.